# How verify user by sending same otp to email as well as phone number to allow sign up using azure adb2c userflows

Tags: firebase-authentication, authorization, azure-ad-b2c, auth0

I want to allow my users to register themselves by verifying otp that will be sent to email and phone number simultaneously and allow signup after verification. I am using azure adb2c user flows, 
I am open for changing auth provider to Auth0 or firebase if they satisfy this use-case.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Auth0, you would need to build out the functionality in your application code for a one time password to be sent out to the email and phone number simultaneously. I hope this helps bring some clarification. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for clarifying that its possible to send it simultaneously in Auth0 with implementing some functionality.